# Why is it so difficult to install mxnet package in R?

Tags: r, mxnet

I have tried every way that I knew, and searched a lot. Still not able to install "mxnet" package in Rstudio. I have scanned all possible ways on Apache website as well, but each method has it's own stopping point somehow.

Anyone being able to install mxnet on R recently? (Mac M1)

Famous example is using tutorials from this website:
https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.7.0/get_started/build_from_source

but the downloaded package has no folder named R-package.

Comment: It is difficult to install because it is a complex piece of software. I myself haven't been able to install a working compiler setup on Mac M1 yet but I haven't tried for a while because I lack the time and nerves. I use an ubuntu setup if I need to compile code in R packages.

Comment: That package seems not ready or very-inconsistently documented. https://github.com/apache/mxnet/blob/v1.x/docs/static_site/src/pages/get_started/osx_setup.md is another source for installation instructions, but this one actually references an R package (unlike the website). I don't use mxnet (nor do I have macos).

Comment: @r2evans thanks a lot for your comments. I want to train a simple neural network (ANN) on some data and tune its hyperparameters. Caret is the only package that I know for doing this. Do you know any other way for tuning ANNs in R? (I've heard about the h2o package as well).